# Re-rendering list template causes page to scroll to top

Tags: meteor

I have some templates that look roughly like this:

```
<template name="items">
  <div class="item-list">
    {{#each items}}
      {{> item}}
    {{/each}}
  <div>
  {{> loadMore}}
</template>

<template name="item">
  <div class="item" id="{{unique_string}}">
    <!-- stuff here -->
  </div>
</template>

<template name="loadMore">
  <a href="#">Load more...</a>
</template>
```

With associated javascript:

```
Template.items.items = function() {
  return Items.find({}, {limit: Session.get("itemCount")});
}

Template.loadMore.events({
  "click": function() {
    Session.set("itemCount", Session.get("itemCount") + 10);
  }
})
```

All that together more-or-less gives me something that pretty much works like an infinite scrolling section.  (The actual code has a few more moving parts, but this is the important bit.)

Whenever I click on `loadMore`, though, it both pulls more data down *and* scrolls me back to the top of the page, rather defeating the purpose of infinite scroll.  I can throw in some javascript to scroll back down to where it should be, but that leaves a nasty flicker as the page hops around quicly.

I've tried using `preserve` on the entire list as well as on each item `div` to keep them from getting updated, but that didn't seem to stop the scrolling.  I've also tried putting `{{#isolate}}` blocks around just about any and everything, without any luck.

Is there something I can do here to make the page not scroll around while it re-renders?  Composing templates differently?  Some aspect of `preserve` or `{{#isolate}}` that I've missed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The page scrolls to top because your
`<a href="#">Load more...</a>` will make the page scroll to top. When your href links to "#" the page will scroll to the DOM element with #"element id". Clicking a link with only "#" will scroll to top.

You have two options:

1. Prevent the default behaviour on the click event (easy option):

   ```
   Template.loadMore.events({
   "click": function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     Session.set("itemCount", Session.get("itemCount") + 10);
   }   })
   ```

   This will stop the page reload
2. Even better: make the `<a href="#">Load more...</a>` link to `"#{{_id}}"` then the page will automatically scroll to the element with the id you provided. This will require some restructuring of the templates and maybe a helper method in the template to give you the id of the last item. But it will make your page load exactly where you want.

Comment: ... of course.  Who would ever suspect that this forest I've been staring at for so long would be _full of trees_.